# Add Featured Image to Existing Post

Tags: php, functions, post-thumbnails

I have already created thousands of product as posts (CSV Import). They have a custom post type. Now, I would like to assign featured image to each existing post programmatically (without manually entering each post and setting the featured images more than 3,000 times).

Additional info:

- Import plugin have not worked out, so I cannot attach the images using CSV import.
- I use a custom field called 'ean' with each prduct, and it is standing as the unique serial number. It is an interger, for example: "5999626322456". The same interger is standing for name of the image (i.e. 5999626322456.jpg).

What code do you recommend to use? I tried these two (among many), but they do not work. What do I do wrong?

```
function set_post_thumbnail( $post, $thumbnail_id ) {
    $post    = get_post( $post );
    $ean_url = rwmb_get_value( 'ean' );
    $kep_url = $ean_url . '.jpg';
    $thumbnail_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $kep_url );
    if ( $post && $thumbnail_id && get_post( $thumbnail_id ) ) {
        if ( wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail' ) ) {
            return update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', $thumbnail_id );
        } else {
            return delete_post_meta( $post->ID, '_thumbnail_id' );
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

```
// Add Featured Image to Post

$ean_url          = rwmb_get_value( 'ean' );
$image_url        = '/wp-content/uploads/' . $ean_url . '.jpg'; // Define the image URL here
$image_name       = $ean_url . '.jpg';
$upload_dir       = wp_upload_dir(); // Set upload folder
$image_data       = file_get_contents($image_url); // Get image data
$unique_file_name = wp_unique_filename( $upload_dir['path'], $image_name ); // Generate unique name
$filename         = basename( $unique_file_name ); // Create image file name

// Check folder permission and define file location
if( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
    $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
} else {
    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
}

// Create the image  file on the server
file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );

// Check image file type
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );

// Set attachment data
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
    'post_content'   => '',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
);

// Create the attachment
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );

// Include image.php
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

// Define attachment metadata
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );

// Assign metadata to attachment
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

// And finally assign featured image to post
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
```

Comment: Have you actually added those images (e.g. `5999626322456.jpg`) into the WordPress media library? If not, are they all already uploaded to the `wp-content/uploads` folder, e.g. `wp-content/uploads/5999626322456.jpg`? Have you considered using the WP-CLI instead?

Comment: Yes, all of them added to the Media Library. No, I haven't considered it, but I open to any solutions.

Comment: So that means, if a post has a `ean` meta with the value `5999626322456`, then the post's featured image is already available at for example `wp-content/uploads/2021/07/5999626322456.jpg`? Is that why you attempted to modify the core `set_post_thumbnail()` function? And are the images all in JPEG format (`.jpg`)?

Comment: Yes, the featured image is available in the Media Library, but not yet attached to the post. This is the reason why I tried to use `set_post_thumbnail()` function. All the images are in `.jpg`. If a more universal solution can work, it is also good for me. I have a gallery custom field, and later I also would like to populate them.